# Can't get POST data from drop down when I clone select tag

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

**Before I use jquery my view code :**

```
<form name="add_book_form" action="Backend/BookManage/save" method="POST">

    <table width="100%" border="0" class="table" id="center" align="center">

         <tr class="author_div_1">
           <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
           <td>Author</td>
           <td>
             <select name="author_1" class="form-control">
               <?php
                  foreach ($authorList as $author) 
                  {
                    echo '<option value = "' . $author["id"] . '">' . $author["name"] . ' ' . $author["surname"] .'</option>';
                  }
               ?>
             </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-sm" id="add_more_author"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="68" colspan="4" align="center">
             <input type="submit" id="submit_0" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
             <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

**script**

```
var count = 1;
var cloned;
 $(document).on("click", "#add_more_author", function() {
    cloneData = $('.author_div_'+count).clone().attr('class','author_div_'+(++count));
    cloneData.find('.form-control').attr('name','author_'+count);
    cloneData.insertAfter('.author_div_'+ (count-1));
    $('.author_count').attr('value',count);
});
```

**After click add_more_author my html source look like :**

```
<select name="author_2" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">First Value</option>
  <option value="2">Second Value</option>
  <option value="3">Third value</option>            
</select>

<select name="author_3" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">First Value</option>
  <option value="2">Second Value</option>
  <option value="3">Third value</option>            
</select>
```

when I click add_more_author and select value then submit it, 
at my controller I echo POST value , First (author_1) just fine but the other I can't get it.

```
    echo 'AUTHOR 1 ' . $this->input->post('author_1') . '<br>';
    echo 'AUTHOR 2 ' . $this->input->post('author_2');
```

**Result :**

AUTHOR 1 1

AUTHOR 2

Comment: could you add `author_div_N` to your source code? I done see it also the form tags in relation to this could be helpful

Comment: How do you submit value?

Comment: I will update my code very soon.

Comment: @AbstractChaos I just updated form tag.

Comment: @kosterz ok try adding this to your php `var_dump($this->input->post());` do it before your current echos do you see the field & data?

Comment: @kosterz as you can see from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43LF6/), the data is being set and read correctly